# Java - possible permutations of an array of numbers which would result in an identical binary search tree

Tags: java, arrays, binary-search-tree, permutation

Given an array of ints which would generate a certain BST, how many variations of that array would result in an identical BST? I have found a few solutions in C++ and python, but nothing in Java. I think I understand the concept of how to develop the correct code.

I'm doing this for a certain Google foobar challenge. When I throw any possible arrays that I could think of I get the correct answer, but when I try to verify my code with Google I get an ArithmeticException. I cannot find where this would possibly occur in my code.

I need to return the answer in a String and the parameter can be an array with a  maximum of 50 integers.

This is the code I currently have:

```
public static String answer(int[] seq) {
    if (seq.length <= 1) {
        return Integer.toString(1);
    }

    ArrayList<Integer> rightList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> leftList = new ArrayList<>();
    int root = seq[0];

    for (int i : seq) {
        if (i > root) {
            leftList.add(i);
        } else if (i < root) {
            rightList.add(i);
        }
    }

    int[] rightArray = new int[rightList.size()];
    int[] leftArray = new int[leftList.size()];

    int i = 0;
    for (int j : rightList) {
        rightArray[i++] = j;
    }

    int k = 0;
    for (int l : leftList) {
        leftArray[k++] = l;
    }

    int recurseLeft = Integer.parseInt(answer(leftArray));
    int recurseRight = Integer.parseInt(answer(rightArray));

    return Integer.toString(recurseLeft * recurseRight
            * interleave(leftList.size(), rightList.size()));
}

private static int interleave(int a, int b) {
    return (factorial(a + b)) / ((factorial(a) * factorial(b)));
}

private static int factorial(int n) {
    return (n <= 1 ? 1 : n * factorial(n - 1));
}
```

Can someone help find either a bug or a possible array of integers that would cause an ArithmeticException?

Comment: `factorial(a) * factorial(b)` might overflow. For example `34! mod 2^31 = 0`.

Comment: So an array like this `int[] arr = {1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2};` will throw the exception.

Comment: @Alexis You should probably put that in an answer.

Comment: Why does answer return a string which it parses to an int? That's odd?

Comment: @Alexis one of the parameters is that every integer is different. Having twenty 2's isn't really an option. David the challenge requires me to return the answer in a string, so I gotta parse it in order to do arithmetic with it

Comment: @OverflowingJava Ok then `int[] arr = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35};`. Doesn't matter. It suffices that my first comment hold to throw the exception. So here the BST generated is degenerated, as the root is `1` and the 34 remaining elements are in the right subtree.

Comment: @AlexisC. You're right. Thanks for noticing that. You can put that as an answer and I'll mark as correct answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can someone help find either a bug or a possible array of integers
>   that would cause an ArithmeticException?

The `ArithmeticException` is likely thrown because you divide a number by 0. Adding the stacktrace would have helped to identify where it occurs, but you're performing a division in the `interleave` method.

`factorial(a) * factorial(b)` is an integer multiplication. If the result is too large to fit for the max value an integer can have, it will overflow.

For instance 34! mod 2<sup>41</sup> = 0. So it suffices that you have a degenerated BST where all the elements are superior than the root (which is the first element of your array here) with 35 elements to get an exception.

Hence the following array:

```
int[] arr = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,3‌​0,31,32,33,34,35};
```

will throw it.

Answer (score 1):

`ArithmeticException` is thrown when you try to divide by zero. The only place in your code to use division is `interleave` function